# How to make Modeless modal close after script runs for 5 seconds in google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm building a check-in sheet for a Non Profits toy drive in google sheets. Whenever a guest is checked in, a sheet updates with the guests info and a sound plays in modeless modal. After the sound is played for a few seconds, I would like the modal to close, but it doesnt seem to work no mater what I try.

Here's what I tried.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var editedRow = e.range.getRow();

  
  // Check if a new row has been added
  if (editedRow === lastRow) {

  const html = `
  <audio controls autoplay>
     <source src="INSERT LINK" type="audio/mp3">
  </audio>
  <script>
    const audio = document.getElementById('audioPlayer');
    audio.oncanplay = function() {
      audio.play();
      setTimeout(() => google.script.host.close(), 5000);
    
    };
  </script>
  `;

  const dialog = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setTitle('Play').setWidth(300).setHeight(50);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(dialog, 'Play Audio');

}
```

Everything seems to work fine but the does not close after the specified timeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About `After the sound is played for a few seconds, I would like the modal to close`, when your showing script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### Modification points:

- In your HTML, the ID of `audioPlayer` is not found.
- In your situation, I guess that the installable trigger might be used. But, you are using the function of `onEdit`. In this case, when the trigger is run, `onEdit` is run 2 times.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please install the OnEdit trigger to `installedEdit`. By this, when the trigger is run, only `installedEdit` is run.

```js
function installedEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var editedRow = e.range.getRow();


  // Check if a new row has been added
  if (editedRow === lastRow) {

    const html = `
  <audio controls id="audioPlayer">
     <source src="INSERT LINK" type="audio/mp3">
  </audio>
  <script>
    const audio = document.getElementById('audioPlayer');
    audio.oncanplay = function() {
      audio.play();
      setTimeout(() => google.script.host.close(), 5000);
    
    };
  </script>
  `;

    const dialog = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setTitle('Play').setWidth(300).setHeight(50);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(dialog, 'Play Audio');

  }
}
```